# How do I get NetBeans to stop using MRU style tabbing when switching between editors using CTRL+TAB?

Tags: netbeans, ide

I am accustomed to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> switching to the next and previous tabs, respectively, in the order in which they appear on the tab bar.  NetBeans does it MRU style, where <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> will take you to whatever was the last file you were editing.

This often breaks my flow in that I need to keep tabbing and checking if I'm on the right file before continuing rather than just instinctively hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> because I know the file I want to go to is 3 tabs over on the tab bar.

The default <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGEUP</kbd> / <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGEDOWN</kbd> keymaps behave exactly how I want <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to behave, but changing the mappings to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> don't seem to make a difference - it ignores my keymapping and continues using MRU.

How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Resolved the issue myself.  The solution is to use AutoHotKey to map <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGEDOWN</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>PAGEUP</kbd>, respectively.  This will prevent NetBeans from hijacking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> / <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to use MRU despite them having been remapped.

AutoHotKey script below:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; So that we can partial match window title

; Fix MRU in NetBeans
#IfWinActive, NetBeans IDE
    ; CTRL+TAB
    ^Tab::SendInput ^{PgDn}
    return

    ; SHIFT+CTRL+TAB
    +^Tab::SendInput ^{PgUp}
    return
#IfWinActive
```

Hope this will be useful for someone!

Comment: Thanks for the script and saving my time. MRU is really very annoying

Comment: Well, there was a problem in your code. To stop matching `Netbeans IDE` we have to use `#IfWinActive` instead of `{ }`. http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm

Comment: @SantaClaus must have changed in a recent version. Thank you for updating it!